# Get all rows containing the two highest values of a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

The example table looks like this:

```
 last_update | notes
-------------+--------------------
 1449619200  | not that important
 1449619200  | rather useless
 1449705600  | interesting
 1449792000  | very important
 1449792000  | very useful
```

Now I would like to have an SQLite command that outputs all rows with the two most recent update timestamps (i.e. 1449705600 and 1449792000), so that the output table looks like this:

```
 last_update | notes
-------------+--------------------
 1449705600  | interesting
 1449792000  | very important
 1449792000  | very useful
```

What should the command look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from yourtable 
where last_update in (select distinct last_update 
                      from yourtable
                      order by last_update desc
                      limit 2)
```

Comment: Hi there, congrats on 10k :)

Comment: Sorry to crash the party, but if there are more than 2 rows with the same `last_update`, your query may return more rows than expected.

Comment: @sstan..yes i just realized that..will modify the query.

Comment: @vkp: Actually (re-reading the question...), maybe this is exactly what OP wants. Maybe it's ok.

Comment: Thanks, but for the command to fit my needs the `select` command after the `where last_update in` should begin with `select distinct`. I will mark your answer as accepted when it's edited.

Comment: I think it's not correct because select inside main select return 1449792000 twice. Don't you think there should be 'distinct'?

Comment: @user I dont think distinct make any difference on the result. Even performance probably slower because has to compare each result.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza but if you use select without distinct you don't get in output 'notes' = 'interesting' as OP wants because you didn't return appropriate last_update. Your internal select return '1449792000' twice and then on this number is performed external select.